# Manifest parsing failed when loading the sample app microsoft-teams-sample-meetings-token

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am following the Readme to get the microsoft-teams-sample-meetings-token app running locally .
I got the app from github https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-meetings-token

Most of the steps completed without issue, until loading the custom app manifest,
I got an error like this

"Manifest parsing has failed.
For more information, please visit aka.ms/teamsdocs"

my manifest look like below. how can I tell what's wrong with tis manifest?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-app-schema/preview/DevPreview/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "devPreview",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "addac13a-3ab7-43af-8cdb-feb5248cf08a",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.sample.meetingtoken",
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "addac13a-3ab7-43af-8cdb-feb5248cf08a",
    "resource": "api://32c70efa94ea.ngrok.io"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "[companyName]",
    "websiteUrl": "[websiteUrl]",
    "privacyUrl": "[privacyUrl]",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "[termsOfUseUrl]"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Meeting Token App"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Meeting Token App",
    "full": "Token app optimized for meetings to generate sequential tokens for participants"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#ffffff",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://32c70efa94ea.ngrok.io/configure.html",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "context": [
        "meetingChatTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingSidePanel"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "32c70efa94ea.ngrok.io"
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "addac13a-3ab7-43af-8cdb-feb5248cf08a",
      "scopes": [
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "needsChannelSelector": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "groupchat"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "reset",
              "description": "reset the settings for the bot in the service"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you change the web/privacy/termofuse URL ? As @user2590928 - please check the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried already, one useful way of finding specific issues with the app manifest is to add "App Studio" as an app in teams.

You should see the manifests you've been working with - if you go to "Test and distribute" it will parse your manifest and point out any potential problems.

[image: App Studio-Test & Distribute Screen]

Comment: Teams sample app is using the "manifestVersion": "devPreview", it is immediately rejected by the app studio

Comment: I built my app using the vscode extension tool, it's created my manifestVersion as 1.8
The definition for version 1.8 is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema
Try comparing your schema to that